# C: Check if a set of five cards forms a full house or not

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int num[13] = {0};
    char poker[5];

    // input a set of five cards
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf(" %c", &poker[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (poker[i] == '10') num[9]++;  // how do I modify this line?
        if (poker[i] == 'J')  num[10]++;
        if (poker[i] == 'Q')  num[11]++;
        if (poker[i] == 'K')  num[12]++;
        if (poker[i] == 'A')  num[0]++;
        if (poker[i] >= '2' && poker[i] <= '9') {
            num[poker[i] - '0' - 1]++;
        }
    }

    int check = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        // if num[i] != 2 or 3 then it's not full house
        if (num[i] == 1 || num[i] > 3) {
            check = 0;
        }
    }

    if (check) {
        printf("YES\n");
    } else {
        printf("NO\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works properly, except for the input data containing '10'.

**example stdin**

`10 10 10 K A`

**expected stdout**

`NO`

However, my program will recognize it as full house.

I think the reason why it goes wrong is that '10' is actually not a character.

Is there any way to modify my code and solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different char to represent 10 like 'T'

Comment: stdin is unchangeable

Comment: Unchangeable stdin sounds like input from a competition. A quick fix could be to scan a string instead of a char with `char buf[5]; scanf("%4s", buf)` and then take just the first char: `poker[i] = *buf;`. A ten will now be represented by the character `'1'`.

Comment: how could you have a char array of size 5 but '10' be one of the chars?The reason your sample returned YES is because it read 10 10 10 K A as 1 0 1 0 1 and since there were three ones it thought there was a full house.

Comment: Can you change your array to hold strings? then this would work fine (just need to change the 'x' to "x" in your if statements

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int count_1=0,count_2=0,A,B,C,D,E,i,j;
   scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&A,&B,&C,&D,&E);
   int arr[5]={A,B,C,D,E};
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<5;j++)
       {if(arr[i]==arr[j]&&i!=j)
        {   if(count_1<=3)
            {
                 count_1+=1;
            }
            if(count_1>3&&count_2<=2)
            {
                 count_2+=1;
            }
        }
       }

    }
    if(count_1==4&&count_2==3)
        printf("YES");
    else printf("NO");

}
```

does this work?

Comment: please use some context and explain why you think this would work or how does it solve the problem